if 文の条件式がスルーされてしまう
以下のコードの55行目の else if (!isNaturalNumber(input[i])  && isNumber(input[i])) についてです。
ステップオーバーで調べたのですが、ユーザーが01と打っても0と打っても、この条件文はスルーされていました。
0、01のどちらの場合も以下の else に飛び、p4の状態になります。
    else
    {
        current_state = p4;
    }

どうすれば、input[i] の最初の要素に0が来た場合、p2に移すことができる（上記の条件文の中に通す）ことができますか？
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// 状態を表す構造体
typedef struct {
    int id; //状態番号
    char text[128]; //表示する文字列
} State;

// 状態の初期化
State init(int i, const char t[])
{
    State s;
    s.id = i;
    sprintf(s.text, "%s", t);
    return s;
}

bool isNumber(char c);
bool isNaturalNumber(char c);

int main() {

    /***** 課題オ 個々の状態の定義をせよ（状態の変数の生成）****/
    State p1 = init(1, "入力をしてください");
    State p2 = init(2, "0が入力されました");
    State p3 = init(3, "数字が入力されています");
    State p4 = init(4, "エラーです");
        /******************************************************** ******/

        /***** 課題カ 初期状態を定義せよ****/
    State current_state = p1;
        /***********************************/

    printf("%s\n", current_state.text);

    char input[32];
    // 入力された文字列を保存する配列．この例では 32 文字以内を想定
    scanf("%s", input);

    int i = 0;
    //一文字ずつ読み込んで処理
    while (input[i] != '\0') {
        if (current_state.id == p1.id)
        {
           
            if (isNaturalNumber(input[i])==true)
            {
                current_state = p3;
            }
            else if (!isNaturalNumber(input[i])  && isNumber(input[i]))//01と打ち込んでもここがスルーされるのはなぜ？
            {
                current_state = p2;
            }
            else
            {
                current_state = p4;
            }
        }
        else if (current_state.id == p2.id)
        {
            current_state = p4;
        }
        else if (current_state.id == p3.id)
        {
            if (isNumber(input[i]))
            {
                
            }
            else 
            {
                current_state=p4;
            }
        }
        else if (current_state.id == p4.id)
        {

        }      
       i++;
    }

    // 文字列を最後まで読み込んだときの状態の文字列を表示
    printf("%s\n", current_state.text);

    return 0;
}

// 数字[0-9]であるか判定 true：数字，false：数字以外
bool isNumber(char c) {
    if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' ||
        c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool isNaturalNumber(char c) {
    if (c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' ||
        c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        false;
    }
}


@user20098 さんの回答を補足すると、他の質問からVisual Studioを使っていると仮定して、それのデフォルト設定状態でのビルド時にエラー一覧や出力のウインドウにwarning C4715: 'isNaturalNumber': 値を返さないコントロール パスがあります。等の表示が出ていたはずです。そうした表示も見逃さないようにしましょう。

ありがとうございます。

上記の状態でビルドすると、
警告には、scanfが無視されました。としか表記されていません。これってもしかして、自分が初期設定をいじってしまったということですかね？？

あるいは逆にインストール時にワークロードとして大雑把に選んだだけだからという場合も考えられます。「個別のコンポーネント」タブでC++に関連しそうなパッケージを全て選んでインストールしてみると表示されるようになるかもしれませんね。

isNaturalNumber関数にて、else節でreturnしていないからと思います。
誤:
    else {
        false;
    }

正:
    else {
        return false;
    }


以下、補足。

コンパイル時に警告を出力するようにすると気付く内容と思います。(gccであれば-Wall)
C言語とC++言語で若干仕様が異なるようですが、returnで値を返さずに関数から戻った場合、未定義動作とのことです。ご利用の処理系(コンパイラ)ではたまたまtrueと評価される値と認識されたため、質問のような動作になったと予想します。

